# how to map count of groups to another dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have 2 dataframes which look like this:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H'],
                    'B': ['C1', 'C1', 'C1', 'C2', 'C2', 'C2', 'C2', 'C2'],
                    'rank': [2, 5, 1, 8, 6, 3, 4, 7]})

Out[3]: 
   A   B  rank
0  A  C1     2
1  B  C1     5
2  C  C1     1
3  D  C2     8
4  E  C2     6
5  F  C2     3
6  G  C2     4
7  H  C2     7

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'B': ['C1', 'C1', 'C1', 'C2'],
                    'C': [1, 2, 3, 4]})

Out[6]: 
    B  C
0  C1  1
1  C1  2
2  C1  3
3  C2  4
```

I would like to select the 3 highest ranked rows (by column "rank") of df1 but can only select a maximum of 4 names per group (column B) and this needs to include the count of rows in each group in df2.

The resulting dataframe should look like this:

```
   A   B  rank
2  C  C1     1
5  F  C2     3
6  G  C2     4
```

Logic:

The count of rows in df2 for group C1 is 3 (leaving a maximum of 1 more rows to select from this group in df1) and the count of C2 is 1 (leaving max 3 rows to select from df1)

item C has highest rank so gets selected, now the total count of group C1 is 4
item F and item G are the next highest ranked and are part of group C2, total count is 3 so less than 4

I tried the following:

```
df1.sort_values('rank').groupby('B').head(4).head(5)
```

but this restricts to select max 4 rows of group in B only to rows in df1 and ignores df2

Comment: I would 'explode' df2's column B, append the result to df1, then groupby B, head(4), remove the elements from df2 (column C serves as a natural indicator), then head again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an idea:

```
max_per_group = 4

# maximal rows to pick from each group
max_sizes = max_per_group - df2.groupby('B').size()

# 4 rows from each group
heads = df1.sort_values('rank').groupby('B').head(max_per_group)

# enumerate the rows within each group
enum = heads.groupby('B').cumcount()

# output
heads[enum<heads['B'].map(sizes).fillna(max_per_group)].head(3)
```

Output:

```
   A   B  rank
2  C  C1     1
5  F  C2     3
6  G  C2     4
```

Comment: hi. thank you for the above but this does not seem to work if df1 has more group items then df2. ie. df has a group item C3

Comment: @idt_tt see updated answer. The answer now allows picking as many as `max_per_group` from those groups that are missing in `df2`.

Answer (score 1):

First, find the number remaining by group:

```py
In [4]: remaining = (4 - df2.groupby('B').size()).to_dict()
```

Then, select that number from each sorted group in your groupby:

```py
In [5]: (
   ...:     df1.sort_values('rank').groupby('B').apply(
   ...:         lambda x: x.sort_values('rank').head(remaining.get(x.name, 4))
   ...:     ).sort_values('rank').iloc[:3].reset_index('B', drop=True)
   ...: )
Out[5]:
   A   B  rank
2  C  C1     1
5  F  C2     3
6  G  C2     4
```

Comment: hi. thank you for the above but this does not seem to work if df1 has more group items then df2. ie. df has a group item C3

Comment: Now it will select up to four from any groups not present in df2